# Why do I get this result from a multiple criteria query?

Tags: mongodb

On mongo, I issue the following query:

```
db.usertest.find({ "events.event":"event0", "events.event":"event1", "events.event":"eventX" })
```

As per the docs here http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#id4 I would expect this to only match documents that had all these three elements in an array.

However, it matches this doc:

```
{ "_id" : "userbruce", "events" : [ { "event" : "eventX" } ] }
```

Why?

The docs say that this format matches documents that "contain elements that in some combination satisfy the query conditions" What is matching event0 or event1?

EDIT: Is it getting confused because I put in the same field each time?

Answer (score 0):

For AND operation in with this data, please try below query:

```
db.usertest.find({$and : [{ "events.event":"event0"}, {"events.event":"event1"}, {"events.event":"eventX" }]})
```

And yes, the confusion is because you given same field each time. IF you try something like below document:

```
{
    "_id" : "userbruce",
    "events" : [ 
        {
            "eventA" : "eventX"
        }, 
        {
            "eventB" : "event0"
        }, 
        {
            "eventC" : "event1"
        }
    ]
}
```

then, your query would not have given any result. So, your query stands correct, but the data is not appropriate for that query.